# Is there a risk to save arrays in text field with ACF?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use ACF (Advanced Custom Field) for a quite big project on WordPress.
For the moment i save some arrays in textfields. I know it's not clearest way.
Is converting those array in JSON the solution ?
It actually works without doing anything, but I don't know anything in database, i'm afraid that i causes problems.

Here is an example of this array. From their frontend profil, each user can fill a form that add a new experience.

```
Array(
[0] = Array(
      ['name'] = 'First Experience',
      ['description'] = 'fjdjfdkhfkbdsq',
),
[1] = Array(
      ['name'] = 'Second Experience',
      ['description'] = 'jbfhjdsjbfsduf',
),
[2] = Array(
      ['name'] = 'Third Experience',
      ['description'] = 'hbfhdishuqfdsfq',
))
```

And here is the field configuration :

```
{
        "key": "field_5ebfc23830fd7",
        "label": "Experiences",
        "name": "player_experiences",
        "type": "text",
        "instructions": "",
        "required": 0,
        "conditional_logic": 0,
        "wrapper": {
            "width": "",
            "class": "",
            "id": ""
        },
        "default_value": "",
        "placeholder": "",
        "prepend": "",
        "append": "",
        "maxlength": ""
    }
```

As i have not access to the database i can't really check, so do you think it can have any issues ?

Thanks all, might ne stupid ;)

Comment: you need to look at how you want to use the data. If you need to be able to select records by values within those arrays, then it might become inefficient.  Read up on DB design and also on wordpress meta records, eg: usermeta, postmeta etc.  The more you can work with wordpress the more wordpress and other tools will be able to work with your data.

Comment: I have differents array. One that stores particular post IDs for a specific user (user can create a post name "teams" and add others users to it, that are stored in a array). Antoher array (so another field) is the ability to add professionnals experiences to your user profil, for the moment there is a form that creates an array that is itself add to a big array regrouping all the experiences.

Comment: Actuallly, all those functionnalities work but as there will be a lot of users, i was worrying about the db ^^

Comment: For the professional experiences,  if you want to be able to query users by their professional experience eg: Select * from wp_usermeta WHERE profession='astronaut'   then you could store add a usermeta record for each user with meta_key=profession and meta_value=astronaut.  You can have multiple of these per user and metakey.

Comment: For the other, it depends what your main line of reporting is going to be.  If mostly for a particular post/team, you want the users associated with the post, and just that post at a time,  then for the post you could store multiple postmeta records for a key 'teammember' with value userid.  OR on the usermeta with metakey teams and value post_id if for example a user can be one multiple teams and your queries are more by user.

Answer (score 0):

By default wordpress saves meta values using php's serialize if they are arrays. So they are not JSON. I think even if you're using acf it will still save the same way. And that should not create any problems with writing or reading data.
But - and that's a BIG 'but' - I totally agree with Anmari, who commented that it is really up to how you want to use your data. Depending on your functionality there may be easier way of storing your data.

Comment: Okay, see it, i have described my functionnalities under anmari comment. Thanks !